# Smart tv resolution issues

Tags: samsung-smart-tv

I am creating the samsung smart Tv application for 1280 x 720. I am using 4.1 sdk. I designed my html also with the same resolution. But the problem is when i checked it in the emulator it is not showing the full content. 
My Html view:
[image: original view]

My emulator view

[image]

when i click the down button it is showing the below content but it is not displaying the contents from the margin even if i prss the left button.

can anyone help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your widget.info files, Samsung TV Apps store what resolution used in this file.
The default is 960x540 so your UI is cutted.

For 1920x1080 resolution is not suggested since the Smart TV Series 4 (ES4XXX/F4XXX) only support resolution up to 768p and causing the apps with 1080p failing to start or just give black screen.

Answer (score 3):

Samsung TV browsers run at a resolution of 960x540 and then are scaled up to fit the physical resolution of the screen. You should design for that size.

Comment: Even in 1280x720 resolution Tv, Is the browser run at 960 resolution ?

Comment: Yes, hence *scaled up to fit the physical resolution of the screen*

Comment: It was, on 2010 year models, on newer models browser can run in 1280x720

Answer (score 3):

Widgets on Samsung Smart TV 2011+ support 960x540, 1280x720, widgets on 2012+ supports additionaly 1920x1080. See [samsungdforum.com guides](http://www.samsungdforum.com/UxGuide/2012/06_application_layout.html).

Samsung Emulator correctly supports only 960x540.

You should test your markup on real device.